# Pusher VS Client request to server every second for changes

Tags: android, node.js, real-time, pusher

I am trying to implement a real-time pushing from my server to a customized android device. (A device which runs on android OS). I can't use GCN because there is no unique token.

---

Here is the deal.

**Problem**

1. I am posting a message from a web portal to the server
2. I would like the message to be pushed to the android device

---

Here are the proposed solution, which is the best?

**Solution 1**

1. Insert the message with a 'create_date' timestamp
2. Let the android device req the server every second to check for any new messages via the 'create_date'

**Solution 2**

1. Use Pusher with pusher-java-client library installed in the android device.

---

I am thinking of using solution 2, which is the most ideal, I think! Since I am not too sure how Pusher works, is the architecture of pusher the same as **Solution 1**?

Any kind souls would answer my question?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With PubNub you can can have your Android client subscribe to a channel in foreground and also in a background service (instead of using GCM) and always receive messages in realtime.

Adding some sort of message id to the message payload will allow you to uniquely identify the message.

http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/380/can-my-android-app-receive-messages-while-inactive

If you need to security for your service, you can enable TLS (FKA, SSL), AES and use our Access Manager to authorize access to channels for each user.

More questions, contact support@pubnub.com

Comment: @CraigConover, thank you for the suggestion. I think pusher itself has a pusher has a java client library.

Answer (score 1):

The architecture is different in two ways:

1. The Pusher service will create a persistent connection between the mobile devices and the service so when new data is available it can be instantly pushed to the mobile device
2. Pusher offers you real-time infrastructure so instead of having to handle multiple polling requests you make a single HTTP request to Pusher and it will *push* the message you send to the mobile client. This is an easier architecture than building it yourself and you see significant benefits if you need to horizontally scale.

### The Code

In the Android app:

```
Pusher pusher = new Pusher(YOUR_APP_KEY);

pusher.connect();

// Subscribe to a channel
Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel");

// Bind to listen for events called "my-event" sent to "my-channel"
channel.bind("my-event", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(String channel, String event, String data) {
        System.out.println("Received event with data: " + data);
    }
});
```

On the Web Server (node):

```
var Pusher = require('pusher');
var pusher = new Pusher({appId: ID, key: KEY, secret: SECRET});
pusher.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {some: 'data'});
```

To ensure that channels can only be subscribed to by the intended recipient of the message you should use [authenticated channels](https://pusher.com/docs/private_channels).

Comment: I am trying to understand. Basically, the difference between polling the server (multi-request) vs socket (pusher in this case) is that socket retains a persistent connection whereas polling the server for changes is basically lots of request and responses to the server that does not really scale?

Comment: Polling has a few drawbacks. 1. If the data updates frequently and the polling intervals are short it can be inefficient on resource usage (client and server). 2. Frequently polling means you need to horizontally scale your infrastructure sooner. 3. If the data updates frequently then during polling intervals the data in the application is out of date (stale)